# Make API Request at a given time to update current radio show Angular2 RxJS

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

I'm working on a schedule for a community radio station and wondered how I might go about updating the current show playing.

I've got as far as polling the server once a minute (not sure this is the way to go, but it would work at a push), but seeing as I have the end time from the API I wondered if I could set it to update after the end time passes and then set up a new Observer with the next end time.

Does anyone have an idea how I might accomplish that, or have a better way to approach updating the current show?

What I'm really struggling with is getting my head around Observables and Subscribers. How can I get access to the current end_time from `radioShow$` to see if it has passed in an `Observable.interval` for example?

I'll be very grateful for any help with this.

```
export class PlayerComponent {

    radioShow$ = new BehaviorSubject({
        start_time: new Date(),
        end_time: new Date(),
        radio_show: {
            id: 0,
            name: "Loading...",
    });

    constructor(
        @Inject('api') private api, 
        private http: Http) {
            Observable.interval(1000*60)
                .switchMap(() => http.get(api + '/schedule/current/show')
                .map(res => res.json()))
                .subscribe(this.radioShow$);
    }
}
```

View player.component.html:

```
<div class="io-radio-player">
  <p class="schedule-times">{{(radioShow$ | async).start_time | date:"HH:mm"}}–{{(radioShow$ | async).end_time | date:"HH:mm"}}</p>
  <h3 class="margin-none">
    <a [routerLink]="['/radio-shows', (radioShow$ | async).radio_show.id]">{{(radioShow$ | async).radio_show.name | uppercase}}</a>
  </h3>
</div>
```

**@martins code works, but this is what I used in the end:**

```
radioShow$ = new BehaviorSubject({
    start_time: new Date(),
    end_time: new Date(),
    radio_show: {
        id: 0,
        name: "Loading..."
    }
});
timer = new Subject();

@Component({
    selector: 'app-player',
    templateUrl: './player.component.html'
})
subject = new Subject();

    let request = http.get(api + '/schedule/current/show')
        .switchMap(() => http.get(api + '/schedule/current/show')
        .map(res => res.json()))
        .repeatWhen(() => this.subject)
        .publishReplay()
        .refCount();

    request
        .subscribe(this.radioShow$);

    request
        .map(response => { 
            // calculate the delay
            return Math.abs(new Date(response.end_time).getTime() - (new Date()).getTime());
        })
        .concatMap(delay => Observable.of(null).delay(delay))
        .subscribe(this.subject);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do this with the `repeatWhen()` operator. You'll just need to use one extra `Subject` that tells it when you want to repeat the request:

```
let subject = new Subject();

const response = {
  start_time: new Date(),
  end_time: new Date(),
  radio_show: {
    id: 0,
    name: "Loading..."
  }
};

let radioShow$ = Observable.defer(() => {
    // return http.get(...);
    return Observable.of(response);
  })
  .do(() => console.log('create new HTTP request'))
  .repeatWhen(() => subject)
  .publishReplay()
  .refCount();

// responses
radioShow$
  .startWith(response)
  .subscribe(val => console.log('Response:', val));

// pooling delay
radioShow$
  .map(response => { // calculate the delay
    // return response.end_time - (new Date()).getTime();
    return Math.random() * 1000;
  })
  .concatMap(delay => Observable.of(null).delay(delay))
  .subscribe(subject);
```

See live demo: https://jsbin.com/kutabiw/6/edit?js,console

This makes random 0-3s delays between each call to simulate where you'd normally calculate the delay.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, this seems gets me much closer to a solution. I've had to rework it for Angular2 https://plnkr.co/edit/vzSXA6vItalQVTQNvzN9. Are you familiar with BehaviourSubjects? As I'd like to maintain `radioShow$` as being one. I'm also not sure where the `http.get()` would fit in to this. Apologies if this is a pain, I'm very new both RxJS and Angular2.

Comment: @Sarcoma I updated my answer a little. You can see where the `http.get(...)` goes. I also added `.publishReplay().refCount()` and `.do()` to be sure we're not making more requests than necessary. Why you need to use `BehaviorSubject`? It's actually not ideal in this situation because `repeatWhen()` unsubscribes and subscribes to its source Observable. We we were using `BehaviorSubject` than we'd always receive the default value. I guess there should be a way for you not to use `BehaviorSubject` at all.

Comment: Thanks again, I'll take another look. I'm using `BehaviourSubject` to set the initial values, once I get a response they are replaced with the new content, I don't really understand what is or how it does it but it means all my calls `(radioShow$ | async).name` etc. only make one request and don't need `?` like `(radioShow$ | async).?name`.

Comment: If you want to start by receiving the default response objects you can use `.startWith(response)` instead (see updated code). I think you don't need `?` because when you use a filter it needs to get its result before accessing the `.name` property.

Comment: This gets the data and logs it to the console, I'm just missing how I get that data in to my view. I've added the view to see if we have our wires crossed somewhere, I want the `radioShow$` variable to hold and update the data or, at a least that is what my original snippet was doing.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help I got something working (see above). I'm not sure if a couple of bits are doing anything I'll keep working on it, but it's good enough for now thanks again.